# SQL trying to do a JOIN to include results from multiple Tables

Tags: sql, join

I'm a complete novice teaching myself SQL by writing and modifying a few queries and reports at work.
I've got something of a handle on the various types of JOINs and I've used INNER JOIN a few times with decent success.

What I'm stuck on should be a simple task, but my Google-Fu must be weak.  Here's what I'm trying to do.

Say I have 3 tables, Table_A, Table_B, and Table_C, and each table has a column called [Serial_Number].

What I'm wanting to select is 3 of the other columns if A.Serial_Number = B.Serial_Number OR C.Serial_Number.

I've tried doing:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
  Table_A AS A 
  INNER JOIN Table_B AS B ON A.Serial_Number = B.Serial_Number
  INNER JOIN Table_C AS C ON A.Serial_Number = C.Serial_Number
```

But this always yields 0 results as the nature of the data dictates that if A matches B, it will never match C and vice versa.  I also tried a LEFT OUTER JOIN as the second clause, but this just includes NULLs from Table_C that have already matched on Table_B.

All the searches I have done relating to JOINs on multiple tables seem to be about using JOINS to further exclude records, where I'm actually wanting to INCLUDE more records.

Like I said, I'm sure this is really simple, just needing a nudge in right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, probably a simple example in a [tabular format](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) and your expected result would help clarify this issue.

Comment: A join is horizontal. So if a join on A=B and A<>C at the same time, the OUTER joins will give nulls and the inner join will be empty. So please give an example of some input data and what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of two inner joins here is akin to saying

```
If A.Serial_Number = B.Serial_Number AND    
   A.Serial_Number = C.Serial_Number
```

Using left outer join on the second clause - by which i presume you mean second join - would perform a left join on a result set already filtered by `A.Serial_Number = B.Serial_Number` by the first inner join. Given that `B.Serial_Number` doesn't relate to `C.Serial_Number` you wouldn't expect the an equijoin to return any result from tablec.

What you want is a `left outer join` like you tried but for both tableb and tablec.

```
Select *
From tablea
Left join tableb on tableb.Serial_Number = tablea.Serial_Number
Left join tablec on tablec.Serial_Number = tablea.Serial_Number
```

This way regardless of whether `tablea.Serial_Number` is in `tableb` it will still be returned and thus available to be joined to `tablec`

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. Your output for your inner joins is producing NULLs which is why it is resulting in 0. I would suggest modifying your INNER JOIN.